# I cant delete Woocommerce rest api product from form

Tags: php, html, json, rest

I create delete form but no delete with woocommerce rest api error"Warning: http_build_query() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in" and "C:\xampp\htdocs\api-woocommerce\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient.php on line 138"
I dont understad.I can share form and php code;

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ( $data as $row ) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $i; ?></td>
                    <td>
                    <?= $row['id']; ?> 
                    </td><td>
                    <?= $row['name']; ?> 
                    </td><td>
                    <?= $row['permalink']; ?>
                    </td>
                    </td>
                    <td><?= $row['date_created']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['status']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['price']; ?></td>
                    <td><form action="delete_connect.php" name="delete" method="GET">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"/>

                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php $i++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <td><input type="submit" name="gönder"/></td></form>
```

and  delete_connect.php;

```
<?php
$PRODUCT_ID = $_GET['id'];
?>

<?php echo json_encode($woocommerce->delete('products/',$PRODUCT_ID,['force' => true])); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<?php echo json_encode($woocommerce->delete('products/',$PRODUCT_ID,['force' => true])); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo json_encode($woocommerce->delete('products/'.$PRODUCT_ID,['force' => true])); ?>
```

assuming your using this

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#delete-a-product

Comment: @hulk6hulk you are welcome please mark this question as answered and I will try to help you with the other one

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new on the forum. How do I mark it as completed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589903/i-cannot-update-selected-products

Comment: @Breezer is this possible to bulk force delete product via API? I have tried but the bulk is just changing the status active to draft. I want bulk force delete.

Comment: Is there any solution for bulk force delete?